# sprintf_s() fails with "debug assertion failed" error

Tags: c++

The problem is probably something simple, but I couldn't get it to work after hours of research and editing, so here I post my issue.

I am trying to make a function which receives either a single digit integer or a two digit integer and returns it as a string after converting it to a two integer format (e.g. 7 to 07).

```
char *to_two_digits(int num) {

    char num_str[4];

    sprintf(num_str, "%d", num);

    int length = sizeof(*num_str) / sizeof(char);

    static char *return_string;

    if (length == 1) {

        sprintf_s(return_string, "0%d", num);

        return return_string;
    }
    else if (length == 2) {
        *return_string = *num_str;
        return return_string;
    }
    else {
        printf("Error! Number cannot be represented as a two-digit.");
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

The function fails when the sprintf_s() function is run, with an error that says:

> --------------------------- Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library-----------
>
> Debug Assertion Failed!
>
> File: minkernel\crts\ucrt\src\appcrt\stdio\output.cpp
>
> Line: 261
>
> Expression: format != nullptr

What is the problem, and how can I fix it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where is your [MCVE], and how can we see it? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing a null pointer to the `sprintf_s` function. The pointer that you declare in this line

```
static char *return_string;
```

was never initialized to point to anything. Since it is declared static, it is pre-initialized to zero (rather than just having an indeterminate value).

This is what the message is telling you. There is an `assert` in the `sprintf_s` code that checks that you have not passed a null pointer, and that is what is firing.

You are supposed to pass in a pointer to a buffer that the function can write into. But since you are using C++, you're really just supposed to use a `std::string` for this, which you could then return from the function without needing a static variable.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I will try using the string class instead of using a static variable. However could I also know what edit I should make to make the code functional using a static variable?

Comment: @jake You would need to make the pointer actually point to something. Like a character buffer of the appropriate size. For example: `static char return_string[100];`

Comment: `static char return_string[100];` is one of the codes I tried out before, and is producing the same error. Any idea why?

Comment: I don't get that error, @jake. It works fine for me that way. [Live demo](http://rextester.com/YNB92421). I even tested it in a debug build with assertions active. The compiler is automatically determining the size of the buffer because it's calling the templated version of `sprintf_s`. The code has another failure point, though, one the compiler is warning about: returning the address of the local variable `num_str`.

Answer (score 0):

It's exactly what it says — you're passing a null pointer to `sprintf_s`.

It's that `return_string`, which you did not initialise to point to anything, let alone a buffer of sufficient size for the actual result. Rather than being of indeterminate value, it is assuredly a null pointer by virtue of being `static`, but this assurance doesn't help you.

It's actually not a good idea to use `static` for memory management like this, because your function is 100% non-re-entrant. Usually you'd have your users pass in a buffer of sufficient size for the result, and let that calling scope handle the buffer's lifetime.